# What is name and meaning of double dot

Tags: punctuation

This question is about punctuation. There are three ways that the dot (.) can be used.

Dots can be single, which ends a declarative statement and has other uses. (period)
Dots can be triple, which indicate a continuing list or trailing off... (elipsis)
And double.. (??)

Can you explain the name and meaning of the double dot..

Comment: As far as I know, this is just a variant way of expressing ellipsis. There is no magic about three: it's just a convention.

Comment: Did you ever see two dots punctuation in a professional publication? Where?

Comment: The LaTeX command for it is \hdotdot which suggests it has no special meaning in mathematics.

Comment: Hard to prove, but I suspect that two dots is a simple typo, either an accidental additional full-stop or a 'failed' ellipsis. Incidentally, and strictly speaking, the triple-dot is a single character, but it almost always starts life as three full-stops.

Comment: @mdewey It's non-standard if it is LaTeX, at least, it's not supported on our implementation of MathJax. It should be, of course, it's used for Wirth interval notation, which I can't believe is not mainstream.

Comment: The Unicode character for two horizontal dots (U+2025) is called "Two Dot Leader", but a [**leader**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_(typography)) is not a piece of punctuation with meaning - it's just used to fill up what would otherwise be a gap of whitespace between two related typographical elements (e.g., the title of a chapter and its page number in a table of contents).

Comment: Some use two dots do declare integer intervals: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304662/typesetting-an-integer-interval https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2626944/128290

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any generally accepted meaning for two dots. As you say, one dot is a period, which marks the end of a sentence or an abbreviation, and three dots is an ellipsis, which indicates that text has been omitted, or a long pause in speech. But two dots has no specific meaning.

If you saw two dots somewhere, my guess is that it's a typo: The person meant to put a period and accidentally doubled it, or they meant to put an ellipsis and accidentally left off one of the dots.

Perhaps it has some recognized meaning in some special context. You'd have to point us to an example.